# How to remote debug maven build failure happening on non prod server, from local?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, remote-debugging, maven-surefire-plugin

Maven build is successful on local machine but same java application when build on teamcity server hangs while running integration tests and then fails. Is it possible to debug this server maven build on local machine to understand the cause of failure?

Comment: If you have access to logs and outputs, running it with debug on (`-X`) can help as you will get way more output than a normal build. Other than that, I am not aware of a way to debug it.

Comment: @LucasCampos Thanks for the reply. I do have access to logs and outputs but unable to figure out the cause as it is issue in library used. And not able to reproduce that on local thus looking other ways to debug it.